# why am i getting error while trying to send emails using powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Okay so i'm trying to send one email using powershell v2 to some recipients in a text file named emailtargets formatted in new line. below is the sendmailer script.

```
$emailSmtpServer = "mail.xxxxxxxxx.com"
$emailSmtpServerPort = "587"
$SourceRCPT = "xxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com"
$DestFile = "emailTargets.txt"
$BodyFile = "emailBody.txt"
$SubjectLine = "testing"
$Pass  = "xxxxxxx"

# Start Loop for Email Sending
$file = Get-Content $DestFile
$body = Get-Content $BodyFile

foreach ($line in $file){
    $DestinationRCPT = $line.Split(",")[0]
    $firstName = $line.Split(",")[1]
    $lastName = $line.Split(",")[2]

    $body =(Get-Content $BodyFile) | foreach-object {$_ -replace '\[firstName\]',$firstName}| foreach-object {$_ -replace '\[lastName\]',$lastName}
    $emailSmtpUser = "$SourceRCPT"
    $emailSmtpPass = "$Pass"

    $emailFrom = "$SourceRCPT"
    $emailTo = "$DestinationRCPT" 

    $emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage( $emailFrom , $emailTo )
    $emailMessage.Subject = $SubjectLine
    $emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true
    $emailMessage.Body = $body

    $SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $emailSmtpServer , $emailSmtpServerPort )
    $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
    $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $emailSmtpUser.Split("@")[0] , $emailSmtpPass ); 
    $SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage )
    Write-Host "Sending Email to $DestinationRCPT"
```

Now the question is i keep getting the error below while testing with office 365
[image: error while testing with office365 smtp]

And i get the below error while testing with a different smtp server
[image: error while using other smtp server]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does `Send-MailMessage` not exist in v2?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1  Actually i'm very new to this, still trying to get around. i think it does, but where do i add it in the script?

Comment: You don't need to manually construct the smtp/mail objects, you can just use `Send-MailMessage`.  Check out `Get-Help -Name Send-MailMessage`

Comment: @africonso The first error (from O365) indicates that the credentials you supplied were invalid, the second error indicates that the certificate used by the smtp server is not trusted by your client computer

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 i tried again and added the send-mailmessage command but it still wont work. Please can you edit the script the way it should work let me see?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i am very sure the 0365 credentials are very correct as it is my personal email. so are you saying there is no problem with the script?

Comment: Should that not be `$emailSmtpPass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Pass -AsPlainText -Force` ?

Comment: @Theo i tried but it gave me error.

Comment: Oh well. Was worth a try. Is the left part of your email address really your login name? Try adding the domain as third parameter to `New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential`

Answer (score 0):

Its a certificate validation issue, If you are okay in suppressing it, you can do

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```

before sending the message.

Answer (score 0):

Here a set of samples that should assist you in re-writing this to function.

> Overview of Cmdlets Available in Windows PowerShell  Windows
>   PowerShell 2.0 
>   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714569.aspx
>
> Use this example
>   https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Send-MailMessage-3a920a6d

```
  ...

    $params = @{ 
    InlineAttachments = $images 
    Attachments = 'C:\temp\attachment1.txt', 'C:\temp\attachment2.txt' 
    Body = $body 
    BodyAsHtml = $true 
    Subject = 'Test email' 
    From = 'username@gmail.com' 
    To = 'recipient@domain.com' 
    Cc = 'recipient2@domain.com', 'recipient3@domain.com' 
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.gmail.com' 
    Port = 587 
    Credential = (Get-Credential -Credential 'username@gmail.com') 
    UseSsl = $true 
} 

Send-MailMessage @params
```

Or 
    # Using the PS built-in / online help files.

```
Get-Command -Name Send-MailMessage


CommandType     Name                Version    Source
-----------     ----                -------    ------
Cmdlet          Send-MailMessage 
                              3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility

# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Send-MailMessage).Parameters.Keys

Attachments
Bcc
Body
BodyAsHtml
Encoding
Cc
DeliveryNotificationOption
From
SmtpServer
Priority
Subject
To
Credential
UseSsl
Port
Verbose
Debug
ErrorAction
WarningAction
InformationAction
ErrorVariable
WarningVariable
InformationVariable
OutVariable
OutBuffer
PipelineVariable


# Get the examples and modify per your use case, splatting used to make it easier to read on the forum.

Get-help -Name Send-MailMessage -Examples

# Example 1: Send an email from one user to another

$Params = @{
    To      = "User01 <user01@example.com>" 
    From    = "User02 <user02@example.com>" 
    Subject = "Test mail"
    Credential = (Get-Credential -Credential 'user@fabrikam.com')
    SmtpServer = "smtp.fabrikam.com"
    UseSsl = $true
    Port = 587
}
Send-MailMessage @Params

# This command sends an email message from User01 to User02.
#     
# The mail message has a subject, which is required, but it does not have a 
# body, which is optional. Also, because the SmtpServer parameter is not 
# specified, 
# 
# Send-MailMessage uses the value of the $PSEmailServer preference variable 
# for the SMTP server.


# Example 2: Send an attachment
$Params = @{
    From =  "User01 <user01@example.com>" 
    To = "User02 <user02@example.com>", "User03 <user03@example.com>" 
    Subject =  "Sending the Attachment" 
    Body =  "Forgot to send the attachment. Sending now." 
    Attachments =  "data.csv" 
    Priority = High 
    dno = 'onSuccess, onFailure'
    Credential = (Get-Credential -Credential 'user@fabrikam.com')
    SmtpServer = "smtp.fabrikam.com"
    UseSsl = $true
    Port = 587
}

Send-MailMessage @Params

# This command sends an email message with an attachment from User01 to two 
# other users.

# It specifies a priority value of High and requests a delivery notification 
# by email when the email messages are delivered or when they fail.


# Example 3: Send email to a mailing list
$Params = @{
    To = "User01 <user01@example.com>" 
    From =  "ITGroup <itdept@example.com>" 
    Cc =  "User02 <user02@example.com>" 
    bcc =  "ITMgr <itmgr@example.com>" 
    Subject =  "Don't forget today's meeting!" 
    Credential =  'domain01\admin01'
    UseSsl = $true
    SmtpServer = "smtp.fabrikam.com"
    Port = 587
}

Send-MailMessage @Params

# This command sends an email message from User01 to the ITGroup mailing list 
# with a copy (Cc) to User02 and a blind carbon copy (Bcc) to the IT manager 
# (ITMgr).
# 
# The command uses the credentials of a domain administrator and the UseSsl 
# parameter.
```

Get-help -Name Send-MailMessage -Full

Get-help -Name Send-MailMessage -Online